# Find if any permutation of a number is within a range

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I need to find if any permutation of the number exists within a specified range, i just need to return Yes or No.

For eg : `Number = 122`, and `Range = [200, 250]`. The answer would be `Yes`, as 221 exists within the range.

PS:

1. For the problem that i have in hand, the number to be searched
   will only have two different digits (It will only contain 1 and 2,
   Eg : 1112221121).
2. This is not a homework question. It was asked in an interview.
3. The approach I suggested was to find all permutations of the given number and check. Or loop through the range and check if we find any permutation of the number.

Comment: Are you asking a general approach, or how to implement your idea?  I think looping over all permutations would be reasonable.  For example, the number of permutations for your example number would be: 10!/6!/4! = 210.  The absolute worst case for a 10 digit string would be 252.

Answer (score 4):

Checking every permutation is too expensive and unnecessary.

First, you need to look at them as strings, not numbers,

Consider each digit position as a seperate variable.

Consider how the set of possible digits each variable can hold is restricted by the range.  Each digit/variable pair will be either (a) always valid (b) always invalid; or (c) its validity is conditionally dependent on specific other variables.

Now model these dependencies and independencies as a graph.  As case (c) is rare, it will be easy to search in time proportional to O(10N) = O(N)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit?  My combinatorics/discrete knowledge is limited, but I do not see how you can determine (a), (b) and (c) without enumerating all of the permutations (or ending up with a beast of a system of equations?).

Comment: You can calculate a, b and c directly based on the range.  For example 200..250.  100s digit = 0,1,3,4,..9 is always invalid.  100s = 2 is always valid.  10s is 0,1,2,3,4,5 valid, 6,7,8..9 invalid, and so on.

Comment: Ohhh!  I was thinking the reverse way.  Like looking at the set of permutations as a set of variables.  That makes much more sense.  Thanks for the clarification :).

Comment: Thanks, i think i got the approach you suggested. It should work fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling I saw your answer after posting mine. Can you please look into what I have posted down below. Is it essentially the same? I don't want redundant answers; I will delete it if it is. :)

Comment: How would you work the c cases? for example take the range 120-250, for the second value, if 100s is a 1 then valid values for 10s are 2-9 and if 100s is a 2 then valid values for 10s are 0-5. and once the graph is built, do you use some sort of BFS to see if there is a valid path between first and last position?

Answer (score 2):

Numbers have a great property which I think can help you here:

> For a given number **a**  of value KXXXX, where K is given, we can
>   deduce that K0000 <= a < K9999.

Using this property, we can try to build a permutation which is within the range:

Let's take your example:

Range = [200, 250]

Number = 122

First, we can define that the first number must be 2. We have two 2's so we are good so far.

The second number must be be between 0 and 5. We have two candidate, 1 and 2. Still not bad.
Let's check the first value 1:

Any number would be good here, and we still have an unused 2. We have found our permutation (212) and therefor the answer is **Yes**.

If we did find a contradiction with the value 1, we need to backtrack and try the value 2 and so on.

If none of the solutions are valid, return **No**.

This Algorithm can be implemented using backtracking and should be very efficient since you only have 2 values to test on each position. 
The complexity of this algorithm is 2^l where l is the number of elements.

Comment: I'm not sure the algorithm is efficient if the range is [123;220]

Comment: First can be a 1 or 2. Take 1, second must be greater or equal to 2 and we have a 2. Let's try it, third must be greater than 3: Contradiction. Backtrack, we have tried all second values, backtrack. Now try 2 for first value, second can be 0,1,2 we have one 1 and one 2. Try 1, any value would work for third and we have a remaining 2. The answer is yes and the permutation is 212.

Comment: The backtracking may be expensive with respect to time, I think.

Comment: In general yes, but here, there are only 2 possible values and most of the time, we would find a contradiction relatively early. Unless we use an heuristic, I do think this is a good solution. But you are right, for this to be good we must prove that the problem is NP-Complete (And I think it is, but I might be wrong)

Comment: Maybe you had been right, and backtracking is necessary at most once (I am not sure, but I have such a feeling). Then complexity would be O(I), which would be the best one can achieve. Stated otherwise: Your algorithm searches for the smallest number that can be built out of the given 1's and 2's that is larger than the lower bound of the range.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement some kind of binary search:

If you have 6 ones and 4 twos in your number, then first you have the interval

[1111112222; 2222111111]

If your range does not overlap with this interval, you are finished. Now split this interval in the middle, you get

(1111112222 + 222211111) / 2

Now find the largest number consisting of 1's and 2's of the respective number that is smaller than the split point. (Probably this step could be improved by calculating the split directly in some efficient way based on the 1 and 2 or by interpreting 1 and 2 as 0 and 1 of a binary number. One could also consider taking the geometric mean of the two numbers, as the candidates might then be more evenly distributed between left and right.)

[Edit: I think I've got it: Suppose the bounds have the form pq and pr (i.e. p is a common prefix), then build from q and r a symmetric string s with the 1's at the beginning and the end of the string and the 2's in the middle and take ps as the split point (so from 1111112222 and 1122221111 you would build 111122222211, prefix is p=11).]

If this number is contained in the range, you are finished.

If not, look whether the range is above or below and repeat with [old lower bound;split] or [split;old upper bound].

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the range given to you is: ABC and DEF (each character is a digit).

```
Algorithm permutationExists(range_start, range_end, range_index, nos1, nos2)

     if (nos1>0 AND range_start[range_index] < 1 < range_end[range_index] and
          permutationExists(range_start, range_end, range_index+1, nos1-1, nos2))
               return true
     elif (nos2>0 AND range_start[range_index] < 2 < range_end[range_index] and
          permutationExists(range_start, range_end, range_index+1, nos1, nos2-1))
               return true
     else
               return false
```

I am assuming every single number to be a series of digits. The given number is represented as `{numberOf1s, numberOf2s}`. I am trying to fit the digits (first 1s and then 2s) within the range, if not the procudure returns a false.

PS: I might be really wrong. I dont know if this sort of thing can work. I haven't given it much thought, really..

**UPDATE**

I am wrong in the way I express the algorithm. There are a few changes that need to be done in it. Here is a working code (It worked for most of my test cases): http://ideone.com/1aOa4

Answer (score 0):

You really only need to check at most TWO of the possible permutations.

Suppose your input number contains only the digits X and Y, with X<Y.  In your example, X=1 and Y=2.  *I'll ignore all the special cases where you've run out of one digit or the other.*

**Phase 1: Handle the common prefix.**

Let A be the first digit in the lower bound of the range, and let B be the first digit in the upper bound of the range.  If A<B, then we are done with Phase 1 and move on to Phase 2.

Otherwise, A=B.  If X=A=B, then use X as the first digit of the permutation and repeat Phase 1 on the next digit.  If Y=A=B, then use Y as the first digit of the permutation and repeat Phase 1 on the next digit.

If neither X nor Y is equal to A and B, then stop.  The answer is No.

**Phase 2: Done with the common prefix.**

At this point, A<B.  If A<X<B, then use X as the first digit of the permutation and fill in the remaining digits however you want.  The answer is Yes.  (And similarly if A<Y<B.)

Otherwise, check the following four cases.  At most two of the cases will require real work.

- If A=X, then try using X as the first digit of the permutation, followed by all the Y's, followed by the rest of the X's.  In other words, make the rest of the permutation as large as possible.  If this permutation is in range, then the answer is Yes.  *If this permutation is not in range, then no permutation starting with X can succeed.*
- If B=X, then try using X as the first digit of the permutation, followed by the rest of the X's, followed by all the Y's.  In other words, make the rest of the permutation as small as possible.   If this permutation is in range, then the answer is Yes.  *If this permutation is not in range, then no permutation starting with X can succeed.*
- Similar cases if A=Y or B=Y.

If none of these four cases succeed, then the answer is No.  Notice that at most one of the X cases and at most one of the Y cases can match.

In this solution, I've assumed that the input number and the two numbers in the range all contain the same number of digits.  With a little extra work, the approach can be extended to cases where the numbers of digits differ.